# How do we conclude that $K(a,b) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K \leq E$, $\mathcal{A}_{E|K}=\{a \in E \text{ with } a \text{ algebraic } |K\}$

$K \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{E|K} \subseteq E$

We claim that $\mathcal{A}_{E|K}$ is a field.

$a, b \in \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$ are algebraic $|K$, so $K \leq K(a,b) \subseteq E$, where $K \leq K(a,b)$ is an algebraic extension.

> So, $K(a,b) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$

$K(a,b)$ is a field $\Rightarrow a-b, ab, a^{-1} \in K(a,b) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$

So, we have that $K \leq \mathcal{A}_{E|K} \leq E$ and the extension $K \leq \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$ is algebraic from the definition of $\mathcal{A}_{E|K}$.

Could you explain to me how we conclude that $K(a,b) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{E|K}$  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K(a,b) = (K(a))(b) \Rightarrow K(a)(b)$ is an algebraic extension of $K(a).$ Also $K(a)$ is an algebraic extension of $K.$ So $K(a, b)$ is an algebraic extension of $K.$ In particular, every element of $K(a, b)$ is algebraic over $K.$ (everything is happening inside $E.$)

Comment: Ok!! I see... Thank you very much for the explanation!!! :-)